# Connection String MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP .NET MVC 5 and I want: when I am running the app it should automatically create SQL Data base. That is why, I am using `Catalog=CodeFirstMyDB;`  But it giving me connection String Error. Please help me fix it. Here is some screens...
[CustomerRepository class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsNg6.png)

[And this is web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHbMD.png)

Comment: Does it work if you take out the newline?

Comment: Call me crazy. But can a connection string actually create the DB?

Comment: Are you also using Entity Framework?  EF will create your database if it doesn't exist providing you have enabled migrations.  Your `CustomerRepository` class indicates you are not using EF in that particular sample.  Your connection string looks fine - the connection issues could be any number of things e.g. network, authentication etc.  Can you connect to that database server using Windows auth?  Is it a local instance?

Answer (score 0):

Provided web.config file contains new line between "Initial" and "Catalog" in the connection string. `SqlConnection` constructor will fail with `ArgumentException` with message "Keyword not supported" in this case.

Comment: OK. What Exception are you getting? When you it happens? What is the message? If specified in connection string database does not exists, when you are trying to open connection, Open() will throw `SqlException`. Is this your case?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL

Comment: I have created new sql data base and connected like this <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=Amirsaidhon-PK\MESSAP;Initial Catalog=00002729_DBSD_CW2;Persist Security Info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: And it is giving this exception:  An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL

Comment: It cannot connect to the database server. There can be different reasons. There is MESAP SqlServer instance on the Amirsaidhon-PK computer, or 1433 port  is closed by firewall, or TCP protocol is not enabled for communication in SQL Server.